# How do I write a comment using the Stack Exchange app for Android?

Tags: support, comments, android-app

I am trying to write a comment on a question, on the Stack Exchange app for Android, but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Which version of the app? iOS or Android? You aren't getting an "add a comment" button under any posts, or is it only a select post? A screenshot might help, if you can add one.

Comment: On the android app, it is a question with no answers, but there isn't a comment button, but after someone else has commented, I see the comment button

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like any of your accounts has the 50 rep required to comment on another user's post. I don't know if the button is supposed to show if you have < 50 rep or not, but you won't be able to add a comment unless it's your own post or an answer posted to one of your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the web site which does show "add comment" link even when you don't have the [Comment Everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege, the android app (and likely iOS app as well) does not show the option to add a comment at all.

The web site shows such a message when clicking "add comment" without the required reputation:

> [image]

I can't see any reason why the app can't do the same thing.

Comment: It is a nasty UX fight: Some believe you shouldn't show actions that a user can't perform, some believe you should show disabled options, some believe in a consistent interface. Take your pick.

Comment: @rene very true, but I believe the official app should be consistent as much as possible with the sites.